# PHP regex for a hyperlink

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the PHP regex to convert text containing a URL into a hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024126/what-is-the-php-regex-to-convert-text-containing-a-url-into-a-hyperlink)

How can I turn a string like this:

> My Name, http://www.mysite.com

into

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com">My Name</a>
```

using regex?

Basically I want to autodetect if a URL is present in the string, and turn it into a link if it is. And if a name is not present then turn the link into something like

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com">mysite.com</a>
```

Comment: Why close it? This is not exact duplicate! Here is how you can do it `$str = 'My Name, http://mysite.com'; $link = preg_replace('/([^,]+),\s(.+)/', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $str);`.

Comment: Related/Duplicate: [`make_clickable()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861324/how-to-extract-http-links-from-a-paragraph-and-store-them-in-a-array-on-php/6861706#6861706)