# preg-match thar finds links in text but stop before tags "<"

Tags: php, preg-match

I got this code to find text in a string that looks like links and transform them into an a-tag link. Since I also use tiny mce to input the data this situation often occurs (since tiny mce and other editor loves paragraphs).

string

```
http://www.google.se</ p>
```

and the script produces the link

```
href=" http://www.google.se</ p>"
```

(..hmm just discoverd stackoverflows text to link script works :))

code

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $string, $url)) {


       return preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=\"" . $url[0] . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . $url[0] . "</a> ", $string);

    }
```

how can I change the preg to stop the link when an `<` is found?

plus maybe tips on better text to link scripts. actually where does stackoverflows texteditor come from?

Thanks!

Comment: not a good practice to use regex for HTML parsing, try DOMDocument

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags)

Comment: not a duplicate of How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags? since the sought solution is to match a whitespace at the end and mine is to stop match when the link stops.

Comment: @ajreal I will look into it aswell

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract http links from a paragraph and store them in a array on php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861324/how-to-extract-http-links-from-a-paragraph-and-store-them-in-a-array-on-php), [What is the PHP regex to convert text containing a URL into a hyperlink?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024126/what-is-the-php-regex-to-convert-text-containing-a-url-into-a-hyperlink)

Comment: @Joseph it doesnt match links with whitespace at the end but it matches links that occur in DOMText node values. Regex dont know crap about HTML. Please revisit the question and offered solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/[^\s<]*)?/";
```

Try this one. Replaced \S with [^\s<]