# Find a Link in PHP String and convert it into a Hyperlink?

Tags: php

Find a **Link** in PHP String and convert it into a **Hyperlink** so it becomes **Clickable** and opens in New Tab.

**PHP Code / String:**

```
<?php echo $post_details['description']; ?>
```

**Test Link:**

```
http://www.test.com
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024126/what-is-the-php-regex-to-convert-text-containing-a-url-into-a-hyperlink?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace URLs in text with HTML links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188129/replace-urls-in-text-with-html-links)

Comment: You may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247479/jquery-text-to-link-script

Comment: Thats great it helped me. Plus i want to ask, what if i also want to show a thumbail from that link?

Answer (score 0):

use this library. it automatically detect link from the string and make it clickable. you don't need to create a link just add a string having a link. this library will detect it automatically.

http://soapbox.github.io/jQuery-linkify/

Answer (score -2):

Use this example to solve your problem

```
<?php

function makeClickableLink($text) {
    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})', '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    return $text;
}

// Usage 

// Email address example
$text = "you@example.com";
echo makeClickableLink($text);

// URL example
$text = "http://www.example.com";
echo makeClickableLink($text);  

// FTP URL example
$text = "ftp://ftp.example.com";
echo makeClickableLink($text); 

?>
```

Comment: The POSIX Regex Functions were deprecated as of PHP 5.3 (over 3 years ago)

Comment: `eregi_replace`? This function is deprecated for almost as long as I learned PHP! (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi-replace.php)